# Checking if a checkbox is checked with Javascript

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have been trying to check if a checkbox is checked for awhile. For some reason it is not working correctly it just always says nothing is selected.

Function

```
    if(document.theform.hail.Checked==true && document.theform.wind.Checked==false && document.theform.tornado.Checked==false){
        alert("Hail Checked");
}else{
        alert("Nothing Selected");
    }
```

Form

```
<form name="theform" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post">
      <div class="date">
        From: <script type="text/javascript">DateInput('orderdate', true, 'YYMMDD')</script>  To:<script type="text/javascript">DateInput('orderdatetwo', true, 'YYMMDD')</script>
      </div>
      <div class="checkBoxes">
        <input id="hail" name="hail" type="checkbox" value="hail">Hail<br />
        <input id="wind" name="wind" type="checkbox" value="wind">Wind<br />
        <input id="tornado" name="tornado" type="checkbox" value="tornado">Tornado<br />
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="View Data" onClick="document.theform.action='<?php echo $PHP_SELF; ?>';">
        <input name="submit" type="button" value="Create KML" onClick="generatorChoice();">
```

Comment: You say that wind and hail has to be checked... is this correct?

Comment: this test just checks for the hail

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The property should be in **lowercase.**

```
var theform = document.theform;
if(theform.hail.checked && !theform.wind.checked && !theform.tornado.checked) {
    alert("Hail Checked");
} else {
    alert("Nothing Selected");
}
```

Also, as the above code shows:

- No need to check explicitly against `true` or `false`
- Store a reference to `theform` for better performance

Comment: What do you mean by store a reference to theform?

Comment: @shinjuo: the first line of code in my answer, `var theform = document.theform;`

Comment: Sorry it has been a long day. Thanks for the help

Comment: Also, the message being `Hail checked` is misleading as the `if` tests for `Hail checked ONLY`.

Comment: @Delan Azabani This is just testing the function. That is not what it is going to do when it is finished

Comment: @Delan: I doubt that's production code. If I had to guess, the OP is simply trying to get the conditional to work.

Comment: @shinjuo: long day makes for sloppy, frustating mistakes. I've been there. Go get some shut-eye, you'll write better code in the morning.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Yeah I am just about to. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

```
if(document.getElementById("hail").checked && !document.getElementById("wind").checked && !document.getElementById("tornado").checked) {
    alert("Hail Checked");
} else {
    alert("Nothing Selected");
}
```

Comment: I like the use of getElementById much better.  Cleaner, and much less to chance with old old browsers, AHEM IE... AHEM...

Comment: Personally I'd never think of doing it the other way. Then again I'd also almost never not be using jQuery anyway…

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, the property's called `checked`, not `Checked`.